# How to determine Column Count from a Java ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

I want to display SQLdata in a `jtable`. The first step is to create a `tablemodel`:

```
public DefaultTableModel createTableModel(String sqlStatement) {
    int rowCount       = 0;
    int colCount       = 0;
    Vector data        = new Vector();
    Vector columnnames = new Vector();
    String sql = sqlStatement;
    try {
        open();

        ResultSet rs = befehl.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        for(int i = 1; i<=metaData.getColumnCount();i++)
            columnnames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnnames);
        close();
        return model;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine if my SQL statement selects the whole table: `SELECT* FROM test;`, but if I want to display only the first two columns, `Select ColumnName1, ColumName2 from test;`, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I always thought `columncount` depends on the `resultSet`, which depends on the sql statement. How do I get the correct `columncount`?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java‌​:294)
at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1841)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2585)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720) at Main.KassePanel.<init>(KassePanel.java:186)
at Main.Main.<init>(Main.java:36) at Main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Comment: What is the RMDS? MySQL?

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 2
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
 at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1841)
 at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2585)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2720)
 at Main.KassePanel.<init>(KassePanel.java:186)
 at Main.Main.<init>(Main.java:36)
 at Main.Main.main(Main.java:20)

Comment: ah!!! As I thought! The issue is inside the "DefaultTableColumnModel" class, and Vector isn't it? Keep in mind, Vector starts with 0!

Comment: The Vector doensn't seem to be the problem. The count is always correct but the tablemodel always has 5 columns and wants to fill them...

Comment: It may help if you share the piece of code that actually creates the JTable. Apparently there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: No, the table model has *two* columns but your *calling code* is trying to access more.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is fine. Your assumption about select * is wrong - metadata is based on the query executed

Answer (score 1):

You should use ***DatabaseMetaData*** instead of ***ResultSetMetaData***. I 've completed a java project named **dbproxy** which is designed to manipulate and access relational database's structure (metadata). I will make it an opensource project soon. See my code:

```
@Override
public List<ColumnDetail> getColumns(String table) throws SQLException {
    List<ColumnDetail> columnList = new ArrayList<ColumnDetail>();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String catalog = getCatalog();
    String schema = getSchema();

    try {
        DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        if(databaseMetaData == null) {
            return columnList;
        }
        resultSet = databaseMetaData.getColumns(catalog, schema, table, null);
        if(resultSet == null) {
            return columnList;
        }
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            columnList.add(extractColumnDetail(resultSet));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException("Could not get columns: " + e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Could not get columns: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally {
        DatabaseUtil.close(resultSet);
    }
    return columnList;
}
```

Reference [Apress.JDBC.Metadata.MySQL.and.Oracle.Recipes.A.Problem.Solution.Approach.Mar.2006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0047TEVLY)

Comment: Why? The database metadata won't know how many columns are returned by any specific query.

Comment: I suppose that SQL statement is generated dynamicly by some logic not by hard code. so the select list should be figurd out at the moment it is being generating, not at sql execution time.

Comment: Exactly, and how is the DatabaseMetaData going to know how many columns there are going to be in an arbitrary SQL query? What problem do you think this suggestion solves?

Comment: Sure, At original quesiton point. my answer cannot resolve it. so i gonna delete it. I suggest you can figure out the columns at SQL generation-time, no at SQL-execution time.